# How to save the state of a togglebutton when scrolled out in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, togglebutton

I have togglebuttons in each views from my recyclerview and I set a Data in my Sqlite database which give me the state of the ToggleButton when I quit the app to restore it at the start. It's work fine: when i check a ToggleButton, leave the app and restart it, the ToggleButton has the same state that when i left the app. But the problem is: When i check a ToggleButton, scroll out the view and after scroll up, the ToggleButton is no longer checked **but** if I quit the app and come back, it's checked. How can I save the state of my ToggleButton when I scroll out ?

My code in my onBindViewHolder:

```
    holder.state.setText(item.getState());
    holder.toggle.setChecked(false);

    if(holder.state.getText().toString().equals("yes")) {
        holder.toggle.setChecked(true);
        holder.toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trianglegreenup);
        marks_string =  holder.marks.getText().toString();
        marksint = Integer.valueOf(marks_string);
        marksint--;
        marks_string = String.valueOf(marksint);
        myDb.updateData(holder.id.getText().toString(), marks_string);
        holder.marks.setText(marks_string);
        } else {
            holder.toggle.setChecked(false);
        }
```

Where State is just a string in sqlite Database with default value:"no"

My code in MyViewHolder:

```
toggle =((ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton));
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ){

                if (isChecked){
                    if(toggledown.isChecked()) {
                        toggledown.setChecked(false);
                        toggle.setChecked(false);
                        toggledown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.triangleblackdown);
                        myDb.updateData2(id.getText().toString(), "no");
                    } else {
                        toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trianglegreenup);
                        marks_string =  marks.getText().toString();
                        marksint = Integer.valueOf(marks_string);
                        marksint++;
                        marks_string = String.valueOf(marksint);
                        myDb.updateData(id.getText().toString(), marks_string);
                        marks.setText(marks_string);
                        myDb.updateData2(id.getText().toString(), "yes");
                        state.setText("yes");
                    }
                } else  {
                    toggle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.triangleblackup);
                    marks_string =  marks.getText().toString();
                    marksint = Integer.valueOf(marks_string);
                    marksint--;
                    marks_string = String.valueOf(marksint);
                    myDb.updateData(id.getText().toString(), marks_string);
                    marks.setText(marks_string);
                    myDb.updateData2(id.getText().toString(), "no");
                    state_.setText("no");
                }
            }
        });
```

Where "ToggleDown" is the ToggleButton opposite of Toggle.

Thanks !

Comment: You have to call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @AbdulKawee Ok but where and how ? I don't understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have scrolled up and forth, and pretty reasonably, your `ViewHolder` is being reused.
Now let's analyze your `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
holder.toggle.setChecked(false); // This will result in `onCheckedChanged()` to be called

if(holder.state.getText().toString().equals("yes")) {
    holder.toggle.setChecked(true); // This will result in `onCheckedChanged()` to be called
    // some code here
} else {
    holder.toggle.setChecked(false); // This will result in `onCheckedChanged()` to be called
}
```

So, at least two times you are unintentionally calling `onCheckedChanged()` method of your `ViewHolder`. That `ViewHolder` is being reused and when you first created it you attached a `CheckedChangeListener` and haven't detached it.

In order to remove that listener you have to know when a `ViewHolder` is actually being recycled, which `onViewRecycler(ViewHolder)` exactly tells you:

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know where exactly i need to put the onViewRecycler(ViewHolder) ?

Comment: In the adapter of recycler view. See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled(VH)).

Comment: It gives me an error : Error:(49, 21) error: name clash: onViewRecycled(ViewHolder) in Adapterwomen and onViewRecycled(VH) in Adapter have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
where VH is a type-variable:
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class Adapter

Comment: Override that method correctly, most possibly you have other `ViewHolder`, which is a subclass of `RecyclerView.Viewholder`.

Comment: I don't really understand, so i need to Override this method instead of the ViewHolder ? Because when I put it in the adapter without touching anything else it gives me an error. What should I do ?

Comment: You need to override `onViewRecycled()` method of your `Adapter` class, where you remove listener of the `ToggleButton`.

Comment: But if I remove the listener of the ToggleButton where the code will be given to execute some task when i click on the ToggleButton

Comment: You have to attach that click listener in `onBindViewHolder()` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't updating your model when you are checking the switch. You're just updating the database. Update your model too and your code will work as expected.

Comment: in your oncheckChangedListener: items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setState(isChecked ? "yes":"no");

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when i put this code it cannot resolve the method, why ?